# KDE Wallet & Keychain

Tags: kde, kwallet, keychain

How do I fix it so that I am not asked for my KDE Wallet and Keychain passwords every time that I reboot. I am using Kubuntu 18.04 with the latest updates.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205161/annoying-kde-wallet-service-popup-the-application-kded5-has-requested-to-open

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can disable this feature completely under Settings -> Account -> Wallet, untick "Use KDE Wallet".