# Annoying KDE Wallet Service popup: The application 'kded5' has requested to open the wallet 'kdewallet'

Tags: kde, password, docker

On my Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver LTS, the following popup appears often when working with Docker and I'm not purposely doing anything that would require a password:

KDE Wallet Service: The application 'kded5' has requested to open the wallet 'kdewallet'. Please enter the password for this wallet below.

[image]

The [kded5 man page](https://www.mankier.com/8/kded5) doesn't help me understand what's going on, and I'm not using KDE Wallet, so I always click Cancel, and soon it appears again.

Tried to untick `Enable the KDE wallet subsystem` via `Start->KDE Wallet` but this caused my Chromium to "forget" all saved passwords, so it's ticked again, and Chromium "recalled" the saved passwords again - so it turns out I am using KDE Wallet after all.

Tried to untick `System Settings->Notifications->(drop down)->Wallet->Needs password->Show a message in a popup`, but still it appears.

Q: How to get rid of it without making Chromium unusable, and what is going on? Would be grateful for any hint or link to good documentation. I'm ok if Chromium can be configured to store passwords elsewhere.

**EDIT**: Found the [Chromium --password-store parameter](https://askubuntu.com/a/525062/848513) however the only usable (and halfway safe) way seems to be the default, which is KDEWallet (on KDE). Unless I can install the GNOME Keyring on KDE?

Comment: Similar question (but for me it happens not only after reboot), no answers so far: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109179/kde-wallet-keychain

Comment: Based on the info in this thread and other poking around, I've posted a more detailed [follow-up question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423575/how-do-i-make-kded5-and-plasmas-network-manager-stop-trying-to-use-kwallet)

Answer (score 15):

It looks like this is coming from the keyring package which is used by pip. [Their site](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) lists several ways to disable it. In my opinion the easiest way seems to `python -m keyring --disable`

This way you don't have to stop using kdewallet, but you stop getting those popups from pip.

Comment: I get `/usr/bin/python: No module named keyring`. With `python3` (3.6.9) the module is found, but `error: no such option: --disable`. Probably the option has been implemented in a later version.

Comment: The other methods listed on their site like uninstalling the module should still work for you.

Comment: i knew python was related, i was using protonvpn-cli which uses python, it uses a cross platform keyring thing and it seems to've glitched

Comment: `pip` may be one possible source of this problem, but it appears there are others.  I currently have this issue on two Ubuntu machines (20.04 and 22.04), and `pip` is not and has never been installed on either of them.

Answer (score 10):

I also faced this problem. For me, it was because I had just changed my user password (same as admin) and *kwallet* which I guess stores all the passwords (e.g. Wi-Fi password) wasn't aware of the new password. Because of this, I had to enter my Wi-Fi password every time I logged into the system.

To change the password of kwallet, click on this button inside **KWalletManager**...
[image: KWalletManager]

Just entering the old password (or new, after changing) into the prompt from kwallet [kded5] fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Right on the target, @vaibhavsoni! Different from OP, I was only having this popup when opening the browser - and only from the command line (still didn't find the difference). Just like you, my browser stores nothing on KDEWallet, but the reason was the same - I've changed my password and KDEWallet started asking for it. Just had to make KDEWallet's the same one as my user's. Great one!

Comment: This is the correct answer. I, too, changed my user password and it didn't propagate to kwallet. Thanks!

Comment: I encountered the same issue but I did not change my password. See my answer below https://askubuntu.com/a/1440712/124466

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can disable this feature completely under Settings -> Account -> Wallet, untick "Use KDE Wallet".

Comment: I think you mean `System Settings->Personalization->Account Details->Wallet Preferences->Enable the KDE wallet subsystem` checkbox (the best match I found in Ubuntu 18.04 for your answer), I've already tried it and it makes Chromium unusable because it unfortunately saves all the passwords there. I will edit the question to clarify the requirement of not breaking Chromium.

Comment: After setting this, the pop-up continues to occur until logging off and back on again.

Comment: The problem is that `kded5` wants to use the wallet.  Disabling the KWallet system doesn't stop the problem because `kded5` will keep asking to use it (and throwing the annoying modal) whether you have KWallet enabled or not.

Comment: Yes I have exactly the same problem even though I had totally uninstalled the wallet

Comment: These settings do not exist in KDE Plasma 5.26

Answer (score 5):

After asking the maintainer of kded5 he has indicated that:

> On login, networkmanager tries to connect to the wifi and therefore
> needs access to kwallet. org.kde.plasmanetworkmanagement is a kded
> module so the request comes from the kded5 process.

This means that if we disable KDE Wallet the WiFi password will not be saved when restarting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer gets closest to the source of the problem, but is short of a solution.  The WiFi password is stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<WiFi name>`, which is where Gnome gets it from and why it doesn't pester you constantly for a wallet the way Plasma does.  So the question is, how do we get `org.kde.plasmanetworkmanagement` to get the WiFi password from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<WiFi name>` instead of trying to store it in a KWallet wallet?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue even without changing the password.

One solution is to install KDE Wallet, and the reset the password to no password.

```
sudo apt install kwalletmanager
```

Open the change password screen in KDE Wallet, and save the password with a blank text field.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? Resetting the password in Kwallet has got nothing to do with the system password/system security.

Answer (score -1):

This fixes the problem. I had a user today 05.005.2022, complain about this popup. This is just a little more more explicit because for some people, if this file is blank which was the case for the user I assisted today follow the below instructions;

In the following config file;
~/.config/kwalletrc
IF these lines are not in your config, please add them;

```
[Migration]
alreadyMigrated=true
[Wallet]
Enabled=false
```

Or
If, the file doesn't exist create it and add;

```
[Migration]
alreadyMigrated=true
[Wallet]
Enabled=false
```

Comment: This is another way to do what https://askubuntu.com/a/1205323/115439 suggests.  Adding a [Migration] section if one is not already there is likely superfluous.  Certainly it is not relevant to the issue at hand as it is not present in the file after using the @emvaized solution to stopping the annoying popup.