# Can Plasma's networkmanager store passwords somewhere other than KWallet?

Tags: network-manager, plasma, kwallet

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with Plasma desktop.  When I boot up and login to the computer, I get a "KDE Wallet Service" modal with the message

> The application '**kded5**' has requested to open the wallet '**kdewallet**'. Please enter the password for this wallet below.

I want this not to appear.  In trying to gather the information needed to fulfil this desire, I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1205161) AskUbuntu question which seems to describe the same problem.

One of the [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403227) on that post has this tidbit of information:

> On login, networkmanager tries to connect to the wifi and therefore needs access to kwallet. org.kde.plasmanetworkmanagement is a kded module so the request comes from the kded5 process.

Because my modal occurs when the machine attempts to connect to WiFi, and because it will not connect to WiFi until after I enter my sudo password, I'm certain this is my issue: Plasma's `networkmanager` is trying to get my WiFi password stored in KWallet's default wallet `kdewallet`, so I have to open the wallet each time.

I never asked to use KWallet, and in fact I never knew exactly what it was until today.  On my Ubuntu systems that use the Gnome or Cinnamon desktops, I've never had to worry about wallets or built-in password managers.  Instead, I type in my WiFi password once, and it's remembered forever without me having to deal with it ever again.  This experience with other DEs demonstrates that it is within the realm of Turing completeness for my computer to store my WiFi password without me having to administer a specific password manager for it or to open a password wallet every time I want to use it.

Given that this experience is known to be possible, can it be implemented in Plasma?  Specifically, is it possible to make the Plasma `networkmanager` store my WiFi password somewhere other than KWallet, but instead somewhere analogous to where Gnome and Cinnamon store it, such that I don't have to administer a password manager and open its database manually every time I want to use WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to enter a password for the KDE password manager KWallet, you will need to remove the password by changing the password and entering nothing.  Be aware that this will reduce the security of passwords stored in the password manager.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to have to enter a password for KWallet, it's that I don't want to use KWallet at all.  I'd rather have my WiFi password stored wherever Gnome and Cinnamon store it, which I assume is not KWallet.  Is that possible?

Comment: Idk about Cinnamon but GNOME has its own password manager that works the same way. But you don't have GNOME, you have KDE.